# Configuring the Visibility of the V.S. Code scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Usually when an editor is empty, the editor hides the scroll bar, but when there are just two lines in ***V.S. Code***, the scrollbar is visible. Is there a way to configure V.S. Code so that the scrollbar remains hidden until the number of lines-of-code exceeds the amount of lines that are visible in the editor?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### V.S. Code Scroll-bar

Your not going to be able to get exactly what your looking for, but I will clarify, what you are able to do, and you can decide the best option that works for you. I will attempt to outline the answer to cover the topic in a way that it is useful to anyone else who is looking for the same topic via stack overflow search-queries.

The setting that affects the visibility of the scrollbar is `editor.scrollbar.vertical`, and it is the only one, however; there is also `editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize` which changes the size of the scroll-bar (I guess, as a technicality it can affect its visibility as well, since setting it to 0 hides the scroll-bar).

###### `editor.scrollbar.vertical` has 3 settings, and they are as follows.

---

1. **Auto –** *"Assigning the value `auto` will hide the scrollbar whenever the editor is not in focus."*
2. **Visible –** *"A better name perhaps, would be "Always Visible", since assigning the value `visible` always makes the scrollbar visible, even when working in the workbench, or terminal."*
3. **Hidden –** *"I think we can all take a pretty good guess at what assigning `hidden` does. It hides the scrollbar.... I guess I should point out that this too is a case of "always", as it always hides the scrollbar."*

---

**V.S. Code** is a highly configurable editor, and I personally love it for that reason, but to be fair; **V.S. Code** lacks in configurable scrollbar settings, there isn't a lot that can be done to customize it, and this has lead to several issues and suggestions created in the [V.S. Code Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode). Perhaps the most appealing aspect to V.S. Code, is there team. The VSC team listens to suggestions, as they deliver when a suggestion is popular, perhaps [try creating a suggestion](https://github.com/issues) — just remember to make sure no one else has already suggested it.

Comment: `Auto` : `The horizontal scrollbar will be visible only when necessary.`  That includes only when the number of lines exceeds the amount that can be shown given the current viewport height.  I downvoted your answer because it is wrong.  Please test it.  "What you are asking for doesn't exist..." is not accurate.  The OP's issue has nothing to do with whether the editor is focused or not.

Comment: SO has changed bud, one liners don't cut it anymore. The community demands quality answers, which requires explaining your answer thoroughly, which you don't do. Last, but certainly not least, I don't know why you think that `necessary` includes _"when it exceeds the lines shown in the current view port"_,??? Necessary means, when you are using the editor. The correct semantics would be "when the editor is in focus".

Comment: Why do I think 'that necessary includes "when it exceeds the lines shown in the current view port",???'  Because I bothered to test it - you still haven't.   A quality answer would include testing it to see if it is even correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting:

`Editor > Scrollbar: Vertical`

the default is `auto`, is yours changed to `visible`?  Which would be always shown.